# From a main app, how can a framework get its own bundle? (Localizable.strings)

Tags: ios, swift, internationalization, bundle

So I have a main iOS app which includes a framework I made.

In this framework, I created a Localizable helper as well as a Date helper.
The date helper has a function `timeAgo()` which can return "8 hours ago". And I want to localize this string. So I have something like this in my framework:

```
public extension String {    
    public func localized(in bundle: Bundle) -> String {
        if let path = bundle.path(forResource: Localize.currentLanguage(), ofType: "lproj"),
            let bundle = Bundle(path: path) {
            return bundle.localizedString(forKey: self, value: nil, table: nil)
        }
        return self
    }
}

public extension Date {
    public func timeAgo(format: DateUnitFormat = .short) -> String {
        let thisFrameworkBundle = Bundle(for: Localize.self) // Class declared in the framework
        //Whatever, just display a localized word
        return "second".localized(in: thisFrameworkBundle)
    }
}
```

When I run local test (unit testing inside the framework itself), the localize thing works. The bundle is found.

But when I call `timeAgo` from my main app, it doesn't work anymore.

I tried to change this line `let thisFrameworkBundle = Bundle(for: Localize.self)` into `let thisFrameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.myIdentifier")`, same thing (so it works within the framework, but won't work when called from the main app).

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I noticed that `Bundle(identifier: "com.myIdentifier")` won't work within the framework because I'm using Cocoapods and it overrides the framework identifier with a cocoapod one. However, I still don't understand why using `Bundle(for: FrameworkClass.self)` won't work from the main app (but works in the Unit Test of the framework)

Comment: Adding a comment to my proposed answer... is "com.myIdentifier" fully qualified? If so, I'll delete my answer (and this comment) shortly - but please look at the link I have to UseYourLoaf. That may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, I can give you two ways. For the last year I've been using this:

```
public func returnImage(_ named:String) -> UIImage {
    let myBundle = Bundle.init(identifier: "com.[company].[framework]")
    let imagePath = (myBundle?.path(forResource: "images", ofType: "bundle"))! + "/" + named
    let theImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
    return theImage!
}
```

The **key** piece is tying the `myBundle` variable to the Bundle ID defines in the project.

I subscribe to a blog called UseYourLoaf. Very, very good resource. Today their [post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/loading-resources-from-a-framework/), contains a very different way to get this - using classes and `bundleForClass`. I just post a comment asking for pros/cons between our approaches.

What I can tell you is if you named a BundleID, you can get to the resources using my routine.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Yes I had the right identifier. You should leave your answer even if it doesn't help me. It might help other people :)